# How to test transaction rollback and commit in go lang

Tags: sql, unit-testing, testing, transactions, go

I have such code:

```
tx, _ := db.Begin()
defer tx.Rollback()

err := db.Insert(foo)
err = db.Delete(bar)

if !err {
  tx.Commit()
}
```

and I don't have idea how to write 2 test cases:

- successfull (data inserted and deleted)
- error (nothing changes)

I was thinking about:

- monkey patching by function injection to method which is doing db operations, and change this function in test
- monkey patching by changing `foo` sql by making it global - I don't like it too much
- make db not allowing delete operation for test time

Each of above options seems to be not ideal, how should I write this test cases?

Comment: I would say that this isn't "unit-testing". This is testing the DB and/or the DB driver, and should be done separately.

Comment: Ok, unit-testing is not good tag for question, but I need to make sure that my method will rollback in case of error....

Comment: Do you implement your own driver.Driver? Or witch dirver.Driver do you  use. If you just want to test the error-rollback case, you can write a driver.Driver for this test case.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my library dbwrap https://github.com/metakeule/dbwrap
that implements a driver.Driver, wrapping around another driver.

It also has a fake driver that you can use like this.

```
 package main

 import (
   "fmt"
   "github.com/metakeule/dbwrap"
 )

 var fake, db = dbwrap.NewFake()

 func q1() {
   fake.SetNumInputs(1)
   db.Query("Select ?", "hiho")
   q, v := fake.LastQuery()
   fmt.Println(q, v)
 }
```

Use the source code of `fake.go` as a starting point.